# Uncaught TypeError: (0 , _redux.combinedReducers) is not a function

Tags: reactjs, redux

Starting a new React with Redux app and Im getting this error (Uncaught TypeError: (0 , _redux.combinedReducers) is not a function) in code below:

```
import { combinedReducers } from 'redux'
import user from './userReducer'

const reducers = combinedReducers({
    user
})

export default reducers
```

I have Redux installed in my project with "npm install --save redux"

Comment: I don´t know if it is a webpack problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's just a misspelling. Change `combinedReducers` to `combineReducers`

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux'

const reducers = combineReducers({
    user
})
```